# Typing the client object in feathersJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, feathersjs

I'm following the feathersJS guide, but in TS and React and I've run into a problem trying to type the client object.

I've written the following code from the guide

```
import feathers from '@feathersjs/client';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io();

const client = feathers();
client.configure(feathers.socketio(socket));

client.configure(feathers.authentication({
    storage: window.localStorage
}));
```

And then a snippet from my top level React file I have and get a type error

```
useEffect(() => {
    try {
      return await client.reAuthenticate() // <- type error Property 'reAuthenticate' does not exist on type 'Application<any>'
    }
})
```

I tried typing client as `const client: Application = feathers();` but then I just get the type error `Property 'reAuthenticate' does not exist on type 'Application<{}>'`. How can I type client?

Comment: Did you add the types? `npm i npm install --save @types/feathersjs__feathers`?

Comment: Yea I did. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try client.authenticate() without any arguments

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this `@feathersjs/authentication-client` library.
Run this commands `npm install @feathersjs/authentication-client --save` and follow [this instruction](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/client.html#setup).

`@feathersjs/authentication-client` declares reAuthenticate methods for you (see [this](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/blob/892c9a3a599c19bb275d001b4e719f486140b97b/packages/authentication-client/src/index.ts#L7)).